# I am new to python, and I stumbled onto a function/variable? and I dont know what it does, can somebody explain please?

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
get_indexes = lambda x, xs: [i for (y, i) in zip(xs, range(len(xs))) if x == y]
```

It is in the context of a tik tac toe program, and if you want to see it, here it is:

```
starting_message = 'Greetings, X Shall Go First And O Shall Go Second. '      

prompt = 'Shall We Begin?(Y Or N)  '   

instructions = 'Pick A Number(1-9)'

box = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" ,"9"]     

               
print(starting_message)

get_indexes = lambda x, xs: [i for (y, i) in zip(xs, range(len(xs))) if x == y]

player_begin = raw_input(prompt)

if player_begin == 'Y':
    print(instructions)

else:
    if player_begin == 'N':
        quit()



player = 'X'

def is_winner(boxes):
    if 6 in boxes and 7 in boxes and 8 in boxes:    
        return True
    elif 5 in boxes and 4 in boxes and 3 in boxes:    
        return True
    elif 2 in boxes and 1 in boxes and 0 in boxes:
        return True
    elif 0 in boxes and 4 in boxes and 8 in boxes:
        return True 
    elif 1 in boxes and 4 in boxes and 7 in boxes:
        return True 
    elif 0 in boxes and 3 in boxes and 6 in boxes:
        return True 
    elif 2 in boxes and 5 in boxes and 8 in boxes:
        return True
    elif 2 in boxes and 4 in boxes and 6 in boxes:
        return True 
    else:
        return False

def is_tie(boxes):
    if all boxes == 'X' or 'O'
    and is_winner(boxes) is false:
        return True
    else return False
    
    
def is_occupied(index,boxes):
    return boxes[index - 1] == 'X' or boxes[index - 1] == 'O'
 
while True: 
    
    if player == 'X':   
        print('Your Turn X')

    else:
        print('Your Turn O')
   
    board = '''                ___________________
                |     |     |     |
                |  '''+box[0]+'''  |  '''+box[1]+'''  |  '''+box[2]+'''  |  
                |     |     |     |
                |-----------------|
                |     |     |     |
                |  '''+box[3]+'''  |  '''+box[4]+'''  |  '''+box[5]+'''  |
                |     |     |     |
                |-----------------|
                |     |     |     |
                |  '''+box[6]+'''  |  '''+box[7]+'''  |  '''+box[8]+'''  |
                |     |     |     |
                ___________________  '''
                                

    player_board = raw_input(board)

            
    if is_occupied(int(player_board), box):
        print('This Box Is Not Avaliable') 
    else:
        if player == 'X':
            box[int(player_board) - 1] = "X" 
            player = 'O' #False
        else: 
            box[int(player_board) - 1] = "O"
            player = 'X' #True
    
        if is_winnerX(get_indexes('X', box)):   
            print('X WINS!!')
            quit()
        elif is_winnerX(get_indexes('O', box)):   
            print('O WINS!!')
            quit()
        elif is_tie(boxes):
            print()
            quit()
        else:
            'return'
```

Comment: You should take a look at what ```lambda``` is how to use/understand it. 
Here for example : https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

Comment: See [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) in the docs.

Comment: To cite the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51): "Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier"

Comment: BTW, according to the usage of `raw_input` this is code for Python 2, even if `print` uses parentheses. Python 2 is dead since the beginning of 2020 and that death was announced over 10 years ago. Switch to Python 3. Now!

Answer (score 1):

It finds the indexes where there are is a `X` or an `O`, depending on how you call it.

Lets say that `box = ['1', '2', 'X', 'O', '5', 'X', '7', '8', 'O']`. Now, you call get_indexes, passing `'X'`, meaning that you want to find the indexes of all the X's, and passing in box, like so: `get_indexes('X', box)`.

The first thing that happens is the `zip`. To see what is happening, let's print it out:

```
print([i for i in zip(box, range(len(box)))])
# and we get:
[('1', 0), ('2', 1), ('X', 2), ('O', 3), ('5', 4), ('X', 5), ('7', 6), ('8', 7), ('O', 8)]
```

Let's look at the first tuple, `('1', 0)`. Well, where did the `'1'` come from? Well, if you look at `box` you will see that it is the first index. That means that the `0` must be the index of `'1'`!

The next part is here :

```
lambda x, xs: [i for (y, i) in zip(xs, range(len(xs))) if x == y]
#     this part ---> (y, i) <--- this part
```

What's happening here is `y` and `i` are beging set to `('1', 0)`. So `y` is being set to `'1'`, and `i` to `0`.

Now we come to `if x == y`. If you remember from the beginning, `x = 'X'`. Well, *y* is equal `'1'` not `'X'`, so `i`, or the index of `'1'`, is not appended to the list.

Skip to the third tuple `('X', 2)`. `y` is set to `'X'`. `if x == y` will return `True`, and the index of y (`i`) will be appended to the list. So after looping through all the tuples, `get_indexes` will return `[2, 5]`.

You could also accomplish the same thing with `enumerate(xs)` instead of using `zip(xs, range(len(xs)))`. Like this:

```
get_indexes = lambda x, xs: [idx for idx, ele in enumerate(xs) if ele == x]
# idx is the index, and ele is current item/element
```